# Why doesn't the appended HTML lines (form validation) stick after i refresh?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

struggling to understand why the append element doesn't work in my JS.
Here's the JavaScript file and the HTML file is below.

JS file.

```
  var ck_name = /^[A-Za-z0-9 ]{3,20}$/;
  var ck_email = /^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$/i;
  var ck_username = /^[A-Za-z0-9_]{1,20}$/;
  var ck_password =  /^[A-Za-z0-9!@#$%^&*()_]{6,20}$/;

  function validate(form){
  var name = form.name.value;
  var email = form.email.value;
  var username = form.username.value;
  var password = form.password.value;
  var errors = [];

   if (!ck_name.test(name)) {
    errors[errors.length] = "You valid Name .";
   }
   if (!ck_email.test(email)) {
    errors[errors.length] = "You must enter a valid email address.";
   }
   if (!ck_username.test(username)) {
    errors[errors.length] = "You valid UserName no special char .";
   }
   if (!ck_password.test(password)) {
    errors[errors.length] = "You must enter a valid Password ";
   }
   if (errors.length > 0) {
    errors.forEach(function(entry){
          $('#errors').append("<li>" + entry +"</li>")
        });
    }
  }
```

index.html

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <form name="form" action="#" onSubmit="validate(this)"  method="post">
      <input type="text" name="name" />
      <input type="text" name="email" />
      <input type="text" name="username" />
      <input type="password" name="password" />

      <ul id="errors"></ul>
    </form><body>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="form-validator.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. The error messages appear for awhile before the form redirects to '#'.

Comment: Hint. The page should NOT refresh. Your validations errors will stick if the page doesn't refresh. Instead of a submit button, use a regular button, bind a click event on it and handle the validation in there.

Comment: Thanks for all your input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that if there are errors, you don't want the form to submit. You should then return `false` when there are errors.

Change these lines in the `validate()` function:

```
if (errors.length > 0) {
    errors.forEach(function(entry){
        $('#errors').append("<li>" + entry +"</li>")
    });
    return false;
}
return true;
```

And change this on the `<form>` element:

```
onSubmit="return validate(this);"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a separate validation button:

```js
function validate() {
    var valid = true;
    var ck_name = /^[A-Za-z0-9 ]{3,20}$/;
    var ck_email = /^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$/i;
    var ck_username = /^[A-Za-z0-9_]{1,20}$/;
    var ck_password = /^[A-Za-z0-9!@#$%^&*()_]{6,20}$/;

    function validate(form) {
      var name = form.name.value;
      var email = form.email.value;
      var username = form.username.value;
      var password = form.password.value;
      var errors = [];

      if (!ck_name.test(name)) {
        errors[errors.length] = "You invalid Name .";
        valid = false;
      }
      if (!ck_email.test(email)) {
        errors[errors.length] = "You must enter a valid email address.";
        valid = false;
      }
      if (!ck_username.test(username)) {
        errors[errors.length] = "You valid UserName no special char .";
        valid = false;
      }
      if (!ck_password.test(password)) {
        errors[errors.length] = "You must enter a valid Password ";
        valid = false;
      }
      if (errors.length > 0) {
        errors.forEach(function(entry) {
          $('#errors').append("<li>" + entry + "</li>")
        });
      }
      if (valid) {
        $('#realSubmit').click();
      } else {
        alert('Please fill out all fields!');
      }
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="form" action="#" onSubmit="validate(this)" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="name" />
  <input type="text" name="email" />
  <input type="text" name="username" />
  <input type="password" name="password" />

  <ul id="errors"></ul>
  <button type="button" onclick="validate()">Submit</button>
  <button type="submit" id="realSubmit" style="display:none"></button>
</form>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Hint.** The page should NOT refresh. Your validations errors will stick if the page doesn't refresh. Instead of a submit button, use a regular button, bind a click event on it and handle the validation in there.

This is a common pitfall for beginning JS programmers, unless you do want the whole page to reload, don't make it reload via the regular form submit action.

Steps

Use a regular button for submission, like so...

```
<input type='button' id='submitMe' value='Submit' />
```

and in your jquery code, do something like so...

```
$(document).on('click', 'button#submitMe', function() {
   // your validation code goes here...
   ...
   return false; // do not make it bubble up the DOM
});
```